# I want to Create a link href='index.php?action='.base64_encode('hello') and echo

Tags: php

```
I tried this:
 echo '<li><a href="index.php?action=".base64_encode('add_user')>
 <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Add User</a></li>';
```

**Its not working**

**Please help me i need it .**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: `echo '<li><a href="index.php?action="'.base64_encode(add_user).'>
          <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Add User</a></li>';`

This what you need ? Please look at the syntax what is add_user ? is it a variable if so it should be $add_user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tri this code:

```
echo '<li><a href="index.php?action='.base64_encode('add_user').'">
<i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Add User</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution it will help

```
<?php
     echo '<li><a href="index.php?action='. base64_encode('username') . '><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Add User</a></li>';
?>
```

Will print out

```
<li><a href="index.php?action=dXNlcm5hbWU=><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Add User</a></li>
```

Comment: So would it be nice to give the chap a corrected string concatenation rather than just tell him its wrong without correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the href attribute properly in your anchor tag!

Its often easier to break these type of echo's up into sections

```
echo '<li>';
echo '<a href="index.php?action="'.base64_encode('add_user') . '">';
   echo '<i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>';
echo ' Add User</a>';
echo '</li>';
```

Comment: Plus sign not shown +Add User but other is all right.Favicon is not in display. like +Adduser while i get onlu adduser